# Getting error like Missing return in a function expected to return 'UITableViewCell' in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

Trying to show 3 sections in a tableview. I have an enum of sections. But getting errors like:-

1. Missing return in a function expected to return 'Int' in "numberOfRowsInSection"
2. Missing return in a function expected to return 'UITableViewCell' in "cellForRowAt indexPath"

```
 enum TableSection: Int {
        case ProfileNameAndImage = 0, FollowAndFollowings, Options
    }
```

```
//MARK:- UITableViewDataSource
extension ProfileViewController: UITableViewDataSource{
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return TableSection.Options.rawValue
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
                if let tableSection = TableSection(rawValue: section){
            switch tableSection {
            case .ProfileNameAndImage:
               return 1
            case .FollowAndFollowings:
                return 1
            case .Options:
                return ProfileOptionViewModel.allCases.count
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        if let tableSection = TableSection(rawValue: indexPath.section){
            switch tableSection {
            case .ProfileNameAndImage:
                guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProfileImageAndNameTableViewCell") as? ProfileImageAndNameTableViewCell else {
                    return UITableViewCell()
                }
                
                cell.userData = ProfileImageAndNameModel(userName: "John", userId: "12345", userImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "bird"))
                return cell
            case .FollowAndFollowings:
                guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProfileTableViewCell") as? ProfileTableViewCell else {
                    return UITableViewCell()
                }
                return cell
            case .Options:
                guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProfileTableViewCell") as? ProfileTableViewCell else {
                    return UITableViewCell()
                }
                
                cell.profileData = ProfileOptionViewModel(rawValue: indexPath.row)
                return cell
            }
            
        }
        
        
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: If using if-let where are the else conditions? These functions are missing return.

Comment: considering that you will never get an invalid section value just remove if let and force unwrap the result. Note that you have 3 sections not 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases you have to return something if the `if let` check fails.

First of all the enum cases are supposed to be named with starting lowercase letter

```
enum TableSection: Int {
    case profileNameAndImage = 0, followAndFollowings, options
}
```

In `numberOfRows` return 0 if the check fails – which actually will never happen

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    guard let tableSection = TableSection(rawValue: section) else { return 0 }     
    switch tableSection {
        case .profileNameAndImage, .followAndFollowings:
            return 1
        case .options:
            return ProfileOptionViewModel.allCases.count
    }
}
```

In `cellForRow` force unwrap the section (the method is not called if `numberOfRows` is 0) and also force downcast all cells. The code must not crash. If it does it reveals a design mistake.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let tableSection = TableSection(rawValue: indexPath.section)!
    switch tableSection {
    case .profileNameAndImage:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProfileImageAndNameTableViewCell") as! ProfileImageAndNameTableViewCell                
        cell.userData = ProfileImageAndNameModel(userName: "John", userId: "12345", userImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "bird"))
        return cell

    case .followAndFollowings:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProfileTableViewCell") as! ProfileTableViewCell
        return cell

    case .options:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProfileTableViewCell") as! ProfileTableViewCell    
        cell.profileData = ProfileOptionViewModel(rawValue: indexPath.row)
        return cell           
    }        
}
```

Note that `followAndFollowings` returns a cell without data. And `TableSection.Options.rawValue` is 2 but you have 3 sections so it's fine to hard code the return value

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 3
}
```